Password-less database connection in Groovy
I am running:

Groovy Version: 4.0.12 JVM: 17.0.11 Vendor: Debian OS: Linux

I try to connect to a Postgresql database using UNIX domain sockets without password. This is the default of psql.
$ psql -c '\conninfo'
You are connected to database "xxx" as user "xxx" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".

Now I try to do the same from Groovy.
import groovy.sql.Sql

def String url = "jdbc:postgresql://"
def String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

Sql.withInstance(url, null, null, driver) { sql ->

But the code throws the error:

Caught: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no password was provided.

It seems to me that the driver does not try to use UNIX domain sockets. How to force the use of UNIX domain sockets in Groovy?

Have you tried what it says in the documentation for the postgres driver? https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#unix-sockets

First you need to add the library that provides unix sockets:
implementation "com.kohlschutter.junixsocket:junixsocket-core:2.5.1"

Then you need to use the correct URL syntax to make it use the unix-socket by adding ?socketFactory=org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketFactory$FactoryArg&socketFactoryArg=[path-to-the-unix-socket]
Your URL might look like this:
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres?socketFactory=org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketFactory$FactoryArg&socketFactoryArg=/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

